# error in keras TimeDistributed layer after updating to keras 3.0.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I use the keras TimeDistributed layer in an LSTM architecture just like the following example taken from https://machinelearningmastery.com/timedistributed-layer-for-long-short-term-memory-networks-in-python/

```
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras.layers import LSTM
# prepare sequence
length = 5
seq = array([i/float(length) for i in range(length)])
X = seq.reshape(1, length, 1)
y = seq.reshape(1, length, 1)
# define LSTM configuration
n_neurons = length
n_batch = 1
n_epoch = 1000
# create LSTM
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, input_shape=(length, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
print(model.summary())
# train LSTM
model.fit(X, y, epochs=n_epoch, batch_size=n_batch, verbose=2)
# evaluate
result = model.predict(X, batch_size=n_batch, verbose=0)
for value in result[0,:,0]:
    print('%.1f' % value)
```

In keras version 2.15 this works, but after updating to verion 3.0.0 it gives the error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling TimeDistributed.call().

Invalid dtype: <class 'NoneType'>

Arguments received by TimeDistributed.call():
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(1, None, 5), dtype=float32)
  • training=True
  • mask=None
```

What is the correct way of writing down the architecture in keras 3 for this example?

(I have also seen the UserWarning about `Input(shape)` and know how to solve it but this is unrelated to the TypeError).

Comment: It's bug. It runs on eager mode and not graph mode. Please report to keras team. Keras V3 API has some changes in behaviour, it is better to report there and not in SO for these time being.

Comment: reported, track here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/18941